# React Native Dimensions.addEventListener not Triggered on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing an issue with detecting screen rotation changes in my React Native app on Android. I have implemented the onOrientationChange event handler as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const onOrientationChange = () => {
        const isLandscape =
            Dimensions.get('window').width > Dimensions.get('window').height;
        setOrientation(isLandscape ? 'LANDSCAPE' : 'PORTRAIT');
        console.log("what is orientation: " + isLandscape)
    };
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', onOrientationChange);
    return () => {
        Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', onOrientationChange)
    };
}, [])
```

However, the `onOrientationChange` function is not being triggered when I rotate the device. And I confirmed that auto-rotate is on. React Native version I am using is 0.67.2.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and get the onOrientationChange function to trigger correctly when the device is rotated. Thank you!